# Make sure state is set before function is called react hooks

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

Imagine you have this scenario

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('query changed');
    setSomething(1)
    getStuff();
  }, [props.match.params.query])

const getStuff = async () => {
   console.log(something)
}
```

I've found in this scenario that something will always be the previous value. So for example if you change the props and something is 2, it will call setSomething(1), and put it into the queue. However, by the time you're inside getStuff, something will still be 2. How do you make it so that the setState function always applies before the next function is called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately

Comment: I'm aware of the state callbacks, but those aren't supported for hooks without outside dependencies. I was under the impression that if you wanted to find the value outside of the useEffect, it would be updated, but apparently thats just not true.

Comment: You would need a separate useEffect hook to call `getStuff()` which would be ran whenever your state changes. Then `getStuff()` will have the updated state.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is when you call `getStuff` it accesses the outdated state value. To get the actual one you could use `useCallback` which creates a function binded with the updated state value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState();
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(0);
  const getStuff = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("something", something);
  }, [something]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("query changed");
    setSomething(query);
    getStuff();
  }, [query, getStuff]);

  console.log("query", query);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setQuery(Math.random());
        }}
      >
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Does it solve your problem?

You could check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lewin-rsvh5?file=/src/App.js:82-634

Answer (score 0):

Your function getStuff is `async` you need to use await, wrap that function in another function and invoke that

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('query changed');
    const getData=()=>{
      setSomething(1)
      await getStuff();
    }
    getData()
  }, [props.match.params.query])
```

you can not see the change in useEffect because useState is **async**, you need to put more bottom your console

```
console.log(something)
return (
  <div></div>
)
```

Comment: when I do this, the getStuff() console log is still incorrect. If I setSomething(1), and then call await getStuff the console log shows 2.